# If $f$ is a permutation and $f=f\circ f\circ\cdots$, then $f$ is the identity function on its domain

Tags: sequences-and-series, functions, proof-verification, permutations

> Let $f$ be a permutation on a set $U$.  Suppose that for every $x\in U$, the sequence $$x,f(x),f\circ f(x), f\circ f\circ f(x), \ldots$$ stabilizes, and let this value of $x$ be called $f^\infty(x)$.  Suppose that $f=f^\infty$.  Then, $f$ is the identity function on $U$.

Here is my take on it. Let $f:U\to U$ be bijective, hence, a permutation on $U$. Then, because $f=f\circ f\circ f\cdots$, then $f\circ f= f\circ f \circ f \circ\cdots= f$, so $f\circ f=f$, and because it is bijective we can take its inverse giving us $f^{-1}\circ f\circ f=f^{-1}\circ f\iff f=I$. Could anyone confirm this? Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand nothing. What's $f\circ f \circ...$? this makes no sense. How many times do you compose?

Comment: countably infinite times.

Comment: Now I'm even more confused. How do you compose infinitely many times? Do you take limits? what's $f\circ f \circ ... (x) = ?$

Comment: Apparently, just $x$

Comment: If we have the set $\{\mbox{on},\mbox{off}\}$ and $f(\mbox{on})=\mbox{off}$ and $f(\mbox{off})=\mbox{on}$ then what is $(f\circ f\circ...)(\mbox{on})$? Like if we toggle a light switch infinitely many times, does it end up on or off? :P

Comment: It isn't defined on that function then, like a function oscillating between 0 and 1 has no limit. Apparently, $I$ is the only permutation that $f\circ f\circ\cdots$ is defined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me try to rewrite the question and please tell me if this is what the question means.  If this is not the case, Ill delete the answer.

> Let $f$ be a permutation on a set $U$.  Suppose that for every $x\in U$, the sequence $$x,f(x),f\circ f(x), f\circ f\circ f(x), \ldots$$ stabilizes, and let this value of $x$ be called $f^\infty(x)$.  Suppose that $f=f^\infty$.  Then, $f$ is the identity function on $U$.

If this is what the question means, then you are kind of correct.  This is because $f^\infty=f\circ f^\infty$.  If $f=f^\infty$, then $f=f\circ f^\infty$.  Since $f$ is a bijection, $f^\infty$ must be the identity function on $U$.  But as $f=f^\infty$, $f$ is also the identity function on $U$.

---

However, if $U$ is equipped with a topology so that it is possible to discuss limits, then this is also a valid interpretation of the problem.  The proof remains the same.  My first interpretation is actually a consequence of the second interpretation.  That is, in the first interpretation, $U$ is equipped with the discrete topology.

> Let $f$ be a permutation on a topological space $U$.  Suppose that for every $x\in U$, the sequence $$x,f(x),f\circ f(x), f\circ f\circ f(x), \ldots$$ converges to a unique limit, and let this value of $x$ be called $f^\infty(x)$.  Suppose that $f=f^\infty$.  Then, $f$ is the identity function on $U$.